# How to retain items checked state in list view

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, adapter

I have a list view in which each item has a check box linked to it. When i check that check box and return to my previous activity i get the selected result but when i go back to the list view my previously checked item are not shown as selected.
If anyone knows how to do this please do let me know.
Thank You.

Comment: maintain a class level boolean list which will hold the state of your check box , i.e true for check and false for uncheck , use this list to mark your check boxes when u return to your activity

Comment: holder.check.setChecked(((ListView)parent).isItemChecked(position));
I used this line in my adapter class but it does not work infact it distorts my whole list

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to save state of all checkbox in database or a file.And then you return to activity read it again and set it on checkbox.
As per android activity all resource are lost while moving to other activities.

Comment: i get all my data from an object which further sets the info to my adapter class and i show that in my list. and the object gets all its information from the server so maintaining a database would not be a solution. 
Thanks

Comment: even with an adapter you will create check box for each list item and and there you can set check box as              checkBox.setChecked(false) AND when you click on check box you can get which check box is clicked and save to database.

Comment: To read which checkbox is clicked you can get it from postion of listview clicked

Answer (score 0):

You probably are recreating your adapter every time you go back to the activity, so you need either to stop recreating it or save the data somewhere. Or if you already have an object with the info you need when you come back to the activity, just send the info to the adapter when you're creating it.

Take a look on the android activity lifecycle, so you can understand better what where to find where you're recreating the adapter: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Although the question is very old, I'm leaving this answer here to try to help future readers.